# Android SQLite db pull error

Tags: android, sqlite, adb

i am trying to pull db from my app but i keep getting this error in eclipse->DDMS->FileExplorer

```
[2014-08-07 12:53:03 - ddms] transfer error: Permission denied
[2014-08-07 12:53:03] Failed to pull selection: Permission denied
```

i tried to do it from CMD with this command

```
C:\Android\sdk\platform-tools>adb -d shell
shell@android:/ $ run-as com.iqpandroid
run-as com.iqpandroid
run-as: Package 'com.iqpandroid' has corrupt installation
```

as u can see the message that installation has currupt installation.. can somebody help?

Comment: Are you pulling from device?

Comment: yes device is attached with root access and debug mode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I am aware you will need to have root access.

From terminal:

```
adb shell
su
chmod -R 777 /data/data/com.your.package
```

Comment: @WasifKhalil No probs, mark the answer as correct :-)

Answer (score 4):

Execute this command from terminal:

`adb root`                     - restarts the adb daemon with root permissions